# Windows 10 not loading DLLs for a release executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2008

Environment:

Windows 10 x64

Visual Studio 2008 (yeah, I know)

Trying to build a very simple x64 C++ application using gstreamer 1.0. The pipeline works just fine in debug mode (even writing images to disk) but the program crashes in **release** mode as soon as **any** gstreamer function is invoked. I've collected the following evidence for the release version:

- Debugging in Visual Studio shows that the required gstreamer/gthread libraries are not getting loaded in Modules tab
- Breaking the path to the gstreamer/gthread libraries by moving/renaming the containing directory (C:/gstreamer/x64_86/bin) has no effect in release mode. If I try this in debug mode, then the application complains at runtime that it can't find the required DLLs.
- Running *dumpbin /dependents*  on the release program shows that there is a dependency on gstreamer/gthread. Same holds true for the debug version.
- Running application from the command line instead of VS produces the same result (a crash)

I noticed that Win10 is smarter and will warn you if multiple DLLs are missing at runtime (instead of just for the first one) but here I'm baffled as to why it's not even loading them and not warning me that they're missing. What else can I use to debug this problem?

Comment: You can try using Process Monitor to see what the process is looking for, and where.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor

Answer (score 1):

Things that have caused this to happen to me in the past:

1. **In a multi-project solution, all of the project build settings aren't synched up.** In other words, if I build the solution in 64-bit Release configuration, does the Configuration Manager show all of the projects being built in that mode, or are some of them left out / or have the wrong build setting?
2. **The 32 bit version of a DLL is sticking around for some reason.** This can especially happen if the build is happening in a non-default directory. In this case, just trash the build directory and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is very tricky GStreamer-specific problem which is tied to the C-Run Time lib. A more careful inspection of the [GStreamer installation docs](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows) by my coworker revealed that GStreamer is using the "ubiquitous" CRT from the Windows Device Driver Kit Version 7.1.0 instead of the regular CRT that comes with Visual Studio. Our first mistake was to attempt to use the VS2010-built GStreamer libraries in VS2008. The second mistake was the inadvertent mix & match of CRT libs.

We were trying to ignore the build instructions which required using props files, as they are meant for VS2010 and we're still dealing with 2008. This was wrong - the props file instruct Visual Studio to use the CRT from the DDK - which one must install separately. [The following section](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows#InstallingonWindows-RemovethedependencywiththeVisualStudioruntime) of the installation docs mentions this in detail. Still not quite sure why this worked in debug mode.